# listener & update issue at ajax in selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.5

I am trying to add selectOneMenu in a datatable column at facet part
(couldn't use column "filterBy" alternative solution because "filterMatchMode" not working with lazyloading which I need a clearFilter,showAll functionality)

I have 4 problems which I couldnt solve:

1. listener at p:ajax not called if I remove "immediate" from
   selectOneMenu
2. update   at p:ajax not done   if I put "immediate" to
   selectOneMenu (I infer that from JSF lifecycle)
3. datatable is not updated when a value is selected at selectOneMenu
   but updated after pressed to select a newer value at selectOneMenu
4. The previous event (table update) occurs if the triangle at
   selectOneMenu pressed at dropping down but not occur if text area
   pressed.

[image]

```
<p:dataTable id="refundOperationLogtbl" var="refundOperationLog" value="#{unusedRefundOperationLogBean.allRefundOperationLogLazyDataModel}"
                        widgetVar="carsTable"
                        lazy="true"
                        paginator="true" rows="#{unusedRefundOperationLogBean.allRefundOperationLogLazyDataModel.pageSize}"
                        paginatorPosition="bottom"
                        emptyMessage="#    {messages['common.datatable.emptymessage']}"
                        rowKey="#{refundOperationLog.id}"
                        resizableColumns="true">

<p:column id="stateColumn"  sortBy="#{refundOperationLog.refundOperationState}" style="width:45px">
    <f:facet name="header">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="menu"  value="#{unusedRefundOperationLogBean.selectedState}" immediate="true" style="width:90px" styleClass="ui-column-filter ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-left">
                    <p:ajax id="menuajax" event="change" listener="#{unusedRefundOperationLogBean.filterStates1}" process="refundOperationLogtbl menu" update="refundOperationLogtbl menu"/>

                    <f:selectItems id="menuitems" value="#{unusedRefundOperationLogBean.refundOperationLogStates}" 
                                    var="emp"
                                   itemLabel="#{emp.label}" itemValue="#{emp.value}"/>
                    <f:converter converterId="RefundOperationLogStateConverter"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{refundOperationLog.refundOperationState.name}"/>
</p:column>
```